# how to save php variable value after defining it, keeping the last value without reverting the value back to empty?

Tags: php

so I want to make a notification with AJAX call, that checks the sum of rows in database, then compare it the amount from before.

when the AJAX access the php file, first it will check if `$old_db` is already defined or not, if not then define it.

then it will run the query(not using prepared statement yet because this still experimental to me) to check, `num_row` query and the store the value into `$new_db`.

after that it will compare the value and goes on.....

then finally it will assign `$new_db` value to `$old_db`

```
if(!(isset($old_db)) && empty($old_db)){
$old_db = "";
}

$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM produk");
$new_db = $sql->num_rows;

if($new_db > $old_db){
    echo "ada";

    echo "<br>".$old_db;
 }

 $old_db= $new_db;
```

**now the problem** whenever I run the php file, it never echoed the value of `$old_db` even though I already assign a value to it at the bottom of the script

I guess everytime I run the script the value got assigned as `""` or `null` again? so how do I prevent that and keep the last value?

I'm thinking about storing it into Cookie....

after thinking about it if I only want to use it as notification then using Session is enough. thank you guys

Comment: Yes, use cookies or session

Comment: so either cookie or session? there really is no other option?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. The PHP script is loaded, executed and removed from memory on every request. In order to persist information between two requests and be able to link them as being submitted by the same browser you can use a cookie or a session (when it's more than one piece of information); in the background, a session uses a cookie that contains the session ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['old_db'] = $old_db;
if(!(isset($_SESSION['old_db']) && empty($_SESSION['old_db'])){
$_SESSION['old_db'] = "";
}

$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM produk");
$new_db = $sql->num_rows;

if($new_db > $_SESSION['old_db']){
    echo "ada";

    echo "<br>".$_SESSION['old_db'];
 }

 $_SESSION['old_db']= $new_db;
```

Comment: thank you. I was wondering if there is another option that I don't know of, but if the only way is to use cookie or session then I will use it